# AsyncTask Execute method showing error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to call execute method of a GetMethodExample class which has extended AsyncTask, but it is showing me the error that the method execute is undefined for the GetMethodExapmle. Here is my code.

GetMethodExample.java:

```
package com.shehryar.httpclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
public class GetMethodExample extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI website= new URI(params[0]);
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

//MainActivity

HttpExample.java:

```
package com.shehryar.httpclient;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import com.shehryar.httpclient.R.layout;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HttpExample extends Activity {

TextView httpstuff;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
    httpstuff=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhttp);
    String data;
    String website="http://www.google.com";
    String extra="";
    try {
        GetMethodExample obj= new GetMethodExample();
        data=obj.execute(website).get();    //Here is the error
        httpstuff.setText(data);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        httpstuff.setText("Error:" + e.toString());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        httpstuff.setText("Error:" + e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That looks ok, can you post the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: And you most likely don't want to use `.get()`. That holds up the UI Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kris Larson for reply but I got my code working just after restarting eclipse. My code was fine but it was eclipse that was making problems

Answer (score 1):

```
    data=obj.execute(website).get();    //Here is the error
```

You are trying to get the data synchronously from an `AsyncTask`.

First, you start the task:

```
    obj.execute(website);
```

Then you override `onPostExecute()` in your `AsyncTask` to handle the finish:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(String data) {

    httpstuff.setText(data);
}
```

Now somehow you have to give the `AsyncTask` a reference to your `Activity` or your `TextView` so that you can update the UI in `onPostExecute()`.

Go read the reference docs on `AsyncTask` to understand how the threads interact and which methods run on which thread.

[AsyncTask | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: otherwise u can use other networking libraries such as Retrofit,Volley :) asyntask is slower than these libraries